# Bash script that downloads an RSS feed and saves each entry as a separate html file

Tags: bash, awk, sed, grep, rss

I'm trying to create a bash script that downloads an RSS feed and saves each entry as a separate html file. Here's what I've been able to create so far:

```
curl -L https://news.ycombinator.com//rss > hacke.txt

grep -oP '(?<=<description>).*?(?=</description>)' hacke.txt | sed 's/<description>/\n<description>/g' | grep '<description>' | sed 's/<description>//g' | sed 's/<\/description>//g' | while read description; do
  title=$(echo "$description" | grep -oP '(?<=<title>).*?(?=</title>)')
  if [ ! -f "$title.html" ]; then
    echo "$description" > "$title.html"
  fi
done
```

Unfortunately, it doesn't work at all :( Please suggest me where my mistakes are.

Comment: Please explain what you plan to do in the second part of your script.

Comment: I want to extract from the feed everything contained in the <description> variable, and then save each time it occurs in a new file that will extract the name from the <title> variable

Answer (score 3):

> *Please suggest me where my mistakes are.*

Your single mistake is trying to parse XML with regular expressions. [You can't](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454) [parse XML/HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/q/590747) [with RegEx](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6751105)! Please use an XML/HTML-parser like [xidel](/questions/tagged/xidel) instead.

The first `<item>`-element-node (not "variable" as you call them):

```
$ xidel -s "https://news.ycombinator.com/rss" -e '//item[1]' \
  --output-node-format=xml --output-node-indent
<item>
  <title>Show HN: I made an Ethernet transceiver from logic gates</title>
  <link>https://imihajlov.tk/blog/posts/eth-to-spi/</link>
  <pubDate>Sun, 18 Dec 2022 07:00:52 +0000</pubDate>
  <comments>https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=34035628</comments>
  <description>&lt;a href=&quot;https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=34035628&quot;&gt;Comments&lt;/a&gt;</description>
</item>

$ xidel -s "https://news.ycombinator.com/rss" -e '//item[1]/description'
<a href="https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=34035628">Comments</a>
```

Note that while the output of the first command is XML, the output for the second command is ordinary text!

With the integrated [EXPath File Module](https://www.benibela.de/documentation/internettools/xpath-functions.html#modulefile) you could then save this text(!) to an HTML-file:

```
$ xidel -s "https://news.ycombinator.com/rss" -e '
  //item/file:write-text(
    replace(title,"[<>:&quot;/\\\|\?\*]",())||".html",   (: remove invalid characters :)
    description
  )
'
```

But you can also save it as proper HTML by parsing the `<description>`-element-node and using `file:write()` instead:

```
$ xidel -s "https://news.ycombinator.com/rss" -e '
  //item/file:write(
    replace(title,"[<>:&quot;/\\\|\?\*]",())||".html",
    parse-html(description),
    {"indent":true()}
  )
'

$ xidel -s "Show HN I made an Ethernet transceiver from logic gates.html" -e '$raw'
<html>
  <head/>
  <body>
    <a href="https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=34035628">Comments</a>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Nice +1 ! I didn't even try to create the files directly from XPath; in my answer I just used XPath for translating the XML to TSV